# Delete lines that contains text with spaces

Tags: regex, linux, sed

So I have a very large file that I created by combining a number of word lists.  The problem is that I made the mistake of not cleaning up the original word lists before combining and sorting them, so there are a number of lines peppered throughout the file that are sentences, ASCII art, or other information that I don't want in there.

For right now, I'd like to delete any line that contains one or more spaces.  I don't want to remove the spaces, I want to remove the entire line if it has a space in it.

I'm terrible with regex, and was hoping someone could help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: `sed -e '/\s/d'` -- run sed with script `/\s/d` which means - for each line matching `/\s/` (have at least one space or tab) run command `d` - delete line

Comment: I've found [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to be very helpful for learning and creating regexs.

Comment: @shisno, Ruby regular expressions may differ from other tools, particularly plain sed uses [basic regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html#ed-regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

There is short command

```
sed -e '/\s/d'
```

It runs sed with script `/\s/d` which means

- for each line matching `/\s/` (have at least one space or tab)
- run command `d` - delete line

So, only lines without any space will be saved.

This command will not delete empty lines.

Use it like:

```
sed -e '/\s/d' < input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Comment: If you want to edit the input file "in place", use `sed -i ...`

Answer (score 2):

I guess an inverted grep for spaces will do the job:

```
cat your_file.txt | grep -v ' ' > output.txt
```

It will filter the file, removing any lines with spaces.

Comment: Also this syntax: `grep -v ' ' < file > out` :)

Comment: I always prefer to use a pipe solution instead of tool options, since I consider it more 'pure' unix approach - one tool to do one job, but do it well. That's the reason I'd use 'sort | uniq' instead of 'sort -u'.
More on the topic - from people who took part in UNIX creation - why cat -v considered harmful - http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/

Comment: hm, is `<` operator not 'pure' unix approach? You use `cat` tool where you don't need :)